# how to retrieve data from database to word document . net

Tags: .net, sql-server, database, ms-word

I have to retrieve the data form database to a word document and excel sheet but I am able to do it for excel sheet & not for ms word or pdf. Can any one suggest me how to do so?
Here is my code in .net:

```
    protected void btnExportToExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=DocumentReport.xls");
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        System.IO.StringWriter stringWrite = new System.IO.StringWriter();
        System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);
        GridView1.RenderControl(htmlWrite);
        Response.Write(stringWrite.ToString());
        Response.End();
    }
    protected void btnExportToWord_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=DocumentReport.docx");
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-word";
        System.IO.StringWriter stringWrite = new System.IO.StringWriter();
        System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);
        GridView1.RenderControl(htmlWrite);
        Response.Write(stringWrite.ToString());
        Response.End();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well. Your code seems to be working at my end. Are you receiving any kind of exception during export? I also received the same a while ago doing the same thing.

I just made **EnableEventValidation="false"** in Page directive of aspx page and it worked. You can try the same.
It should work.

Answer (score 0):

try to change the content type to
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Type", "application/msword");
also make sure if you are using "css" styles to include the styles on the string you are going to render.