# Exporting to large amount of data into Word from .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I remember i had a similar issue with exporting to Excel some time ago and instead of increasing the timeout i have somehow set something to not wait until everything is written into memory before presenting the user with the file, which took care of the large amount of data time out issue.

i am not sure if i'm explaining myself correct, but if anyone knows how to do this, i'd really appreciate your help.

right now i have the following:

```
 docDataSet = m_DataAccess.GetDataSet(adhocSQL)
           response.Clear()
                        response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-word"
                        response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=MyFile.doc")
 For Each dr As DataRow In docDataSet.Tables(0).Rows
'lots of rows and columns here
response.Write(dr("lotsofdatahere"))
next
     response.Charset = ""
                        response.End()
```

Comment: have you looked at any of the `Postings in  the Related` section to the lower right of this page..? check this link for some ideas.
[Exporting Date From Database to Word File](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5468282/how-to-retrieve-data-from-database-to-word-document-net?rq=1)

Comment: this looks like the same way i'm doing it now, except it uses the StringWriter. is that what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, you are simply response.writing some data and letting the browser open up Word.

A few things I would do is determine how much data is going to the browser first, that way you can tell the browser how large the file is it is downloading.  This helps it determine time remaining etc.

Then after X number of response.write iterations do a `response.Flush();`.  This way the data is flushed from the web server's memory and actually written back to the client.

Answer (score -1):

I Think the best solution for this is using reporting services, that would be more easy..